# Find wrongly categorized samples from validation step

Tags: keras, neural-network

I am using a keras neural net for identifying category in which the data belongs.

```
self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.0001),
    metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
```

Fit function

```
history = self.model.fit(self.X,
{'output': self.Y},
validation_split=0.3,
epochs=400,
batch_size=32
)
```

I am interested in finding out which labels are getting categorized wrongly in the validation step. Seems like a good way to understand what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.predict_classes(validation_data)` to get the predicted classes for your validation data, and compare these predictions with the actual labels to find out where the model was wrong. Something like this:

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(validation_data)
wrong = np.where(predictions != Y_validation)
```

Comment: I am providing validation split = 0.3, in that case keras won't tell me which samples were used for validation. But i think i could work around that problem. There is no callback to do this?

Comment: Aha, I didn't pay enough attention. You mean you want to display this information during the training loop?

Comment: it would be nice to see how model learns to identify different classes. Ideally print the data after each epoch.

Comment: how about creating a new metric. It could tell a score for each class per epoch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in looking 'under the hood', I'd suggest to use

`model.predict(validation_data_x)`

to see the scores for each class, for each observation of the validation set.
This should shed some light on which categories the model is not so good at classifying. The way to predict the final class is

```
scores = model.predict(validation_data_x)
preds = np.argmax(scores, axis=1)
```

be sure to use the proper axis for `np.argmax` (I'm assuming your observation axis is 1). Use preds to then compare with the real class.

Also, as another exploration you want to see the overall accuracy on this dataset, use

```
model.evaluate(x=validation_data_x, y=validation_data_y)
```

Comment: `model.predict_classes` combines `model.predict` and the `argmax` operation. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a1397169ddf8595736c01fcea084c8e34e1a3884/keras/engine/sequential.py#L270

Comment: @sdcbr indeed they are. The idea is to be able to inspect the scores first to analyze if theres two or more at similar levels in order to determine where the model struggles.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a metric which prints the "worst performing category id + score" on each iteration. Ideas from [link](https://www.davidtvs.com/keras-custom-metrics/)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class MaxIoU(object): 

def __init__(self, num_classes):                                                                                                                           
    super().__init__()                                                                                                                                     
    self.num_classes = num_classes                                                                                                                         

def max_iou(self, y_true, y_pred):                                                                                                                         
    # Wraps np_max_iou method and uses it as a TensorFlow op.                                                                                              
    # Takes numpy arrays as its arguments and returns numpy arrays as                                                                                      
    # its outputs.
    return tf.py_func(self.np_max_iou, [y_true, y_pred], tf.float32)                                                                                       

def np_max_iou(self, y_true, y_pred):                                                                                                                      
    # Compute the confusion matrix to get the number of true positives,                                                                                    
    # false positives, and false negatives                                                                                                                 
    # Convert predictions and target from categorical to integer format                                                                                    
    target = np.argmax(y_true, axis=-1).ravel()                                                                                                            
    predicted = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1).ravel()                                                                                                         

    # Trick from torchnet for bincounting 2 arrays together                                                                                                
    # https://github.com/pytorch/tnt/blob/master/torchnet/meter/confusionmeter.py                                                                          
    x = predicted + self.num_classes * target                                                                                                              
    bincount_2d = np.bincount(x.astype(np.int32), minlength=self.num_classes**2)                                                                           
    assert bincount_2d.size == self.num_classes**2                                                                                                         
    conf = bincount_2d.reshape((self.num_classes, self.num_classes))                                                                                       

    # Compute the IoU and mean IoU from the confusion matrix                                                                                               
    true_positive = np.diag(conf)                                                                                                                          
    false_positive = np.sum(conf, 0) - true_positive                                                                                                       
    false_negative = np.sum(conf, 1) - true_positive

    # Just in case we get a division by 0, ignore/hide the error and set the value to 0                                                                    
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):                                                                                                   
        iou = false_positive / (true_positive + false_positive + false_negative)                                                                           
    iou[np.isnan(iou)] = 0

    return np.max(iou).astype(np.float32) + np.argmax(iou).astype(np.float32)
```

~
usage:

```
custom_metric = MaxIoU(len(catagories))
self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=0.0001),
    metrics=[categorical_accuracy, custom_metric.max_iou])
```